# Best way to smush pairs of array elements together in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops

Say I have the following:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

How can I convert this into the average of every pair?

That is, how can I make

```
a = [1.5,3.5,5.5,7.5]
```

I mean, I could do

I'm thinking a.step(2), and and then... something involving each_with_index?

EDIT: I see this:

```
arr.each_with_index.map { |x,i| [x, i+2] }

arr.each_with_index.map { |x,i| (x + arr[i+1])/2 }
```

Then filter out all the even indices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`each_slice(2)` and `map` will do the trick here:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].each_slice(2).map { |x,y| (x+y)*0.5 }
 => [1.5, 3.5, 5.5, 7.5]
```

[`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) iterates the array *n* elements at a time, and then we `map` to transform the resulting enumerator.